# Never stops asking for price of the item in while loop

Tags: python

```
def NameAndPrice():
  names = []
  prices= []
  item_list = []
  while len(names) < people_at_table:
    name = str(input("Enter your name."))
    items = int(input("How many items did you have?"))
    item_list.append(items)
    while len(item_list) < items:
        TotalPrice = 0
        price = float(input("Enter the price of the item."))
        TotalPrice += price
        prices.append(price)
        print(TotalPrice)
    names.append(name)
    continue
  print(names)
NameAndPrice()
```

Never stops asking for price of the item in while loop, I want it to ask for price of items for each person and compile it into a final list with [name, price] for each person and their compiled price.

Comment: Neither `item_list` nor `items` are being updated in the inner `while` loop. Obviously it will keep looping forever.

Comment: maybe you mean `while len(prices) < items:`

Comment: @AidenChow what if he enters 1?

Comment: @Chris Then the loop won't even run lol. I wasn't saying it will loop forever for all inputs, just most inputs.

Answer (score 1):

It is going to keep asking for the price of the item because of the innermost `while` loop:

```
while len(item_list) < items:
```

Assuming I understand this correctly, `item_list` will start out as an empty list and then become a list with one element in it before the code enters that innermost `while` loop for the first time. Once inside that `while` loop, `item_list` does not change. What this means is that that loop will turn into an infinite loop, always asking itself whether `1 < items`, which will always evaluate `True`, perpetuating the cycle. You need `len(item_list)` to change inside of that `while` loop in order for it to break eventually.